# Bind Data in List<T> to DatagridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, ienumerable

I am trying to bind data to a datagridview in C#. How can I bind table data to a gridview please.

Below is my code used.

Getting all data.

```
public IEnumerable<MailingList> getAllAddress()
    {
        return Entities.MailingLists.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Datasource

```
dgvAddresses.DataSource = new AddressAccess().getAllAddress();
```

For some reason nothing appears. How can I bind the data please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using a Binding source:

```
     var source = new BindingSource();
     source.DataSource = new AddressAccess().getAllAddress().ToList();
     dgvAddresses.AutoGenerateColumns=true;
     dgvAddresses.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: Updated answer. Try using a bindingsource.

Comment: Use the object initialiser to create the BindingSource e.g. `var source = new BindingSource {new AddressAccess().getAllAddress().ToList()};`