# c# Datatable as Enumerable

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, datatable, enumerable

I've got a Datatable that I needed to run a LINQ query against so I converted it into an enumerable to enable this.

```
var drResults = from r1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            group r1 by new{
                                ID = r1.Field<int>("ID"),}
                                into g
                                select new{
                                    ID = g.Key.ID,
                                    Amount1Tot = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount 1")),
                                    Amount2Tot = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount 2")),
                                    Amount3Tot = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount 3"))};
```

Now this may sound so silly but I have no idea what to do with the enumerable now. My intention was to convert it back to a Datatable which is returned at the end of the method it's contained in. This is then set as a source to a datagridview.
I'm very amateur when it comes to enumerable's so if i can use it while it's enumerable state the same way I can a Datatable feel free to explain.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it back to a DataTable? What would you like to do with `drResults`?

Comment: I have a DataGridView which i'm using to display the results. I want to display drResults in this but only know how to do this through datatable. If this is possible through an enumerable I have no need to convert this back @mason

Comment: Sure you can. See [Bind Data in List<T> to DatagridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404222/bind-data-in-listt-to-datagridview).