# Collections Generic List anonymous type to System Data.IDataReader

Tags: c#, list, datatable, anonymous-types

i have a anonymous list here and trying to load its data to Datatable but getting an error

```
     var empList1 = employees.Select(p => new { UserId = p.UserId, empName = p.FullName, EmpCode = p.EmployeeCode }).Distinct().ToList();

   DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
       // dtt.Load(empList1);
```

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Tool
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Data.IDataReader'**

any solution ??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have a list that i bind to gridview eg:   
gvTest.DataSource = empList;
 gvTest.DataBind();
but then i wanted to export data to Excel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404222/bind-data-in-listt-to-datagridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DataTable.Load` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a `DataReader` but you're giving it a `List<anonymoustype>`. You need to use a loop:

```
DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
dtt.Columns.Add("UserId", typeof(System.Guid));
dtt.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string));
dtt.Columns.Add("EmployeeCode ", typeof(string));
foreach(var employee in empList1)
   dtt.Rows.Add(employee.UserId, employee.FullName, employee.EmployeeCode);
```

This is efficient and readable, but if you need a generic one-liner you have to use reflection: [Convert generic List/Enumerable to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable)

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
on line : dtt.Rows.Add(employee.UserId, employee.empName, employee.EmpCode);

Comment: @ShaikhAamir: what is a `Guid`, the `EmpCode` or the `UserId`? I've edited my code to show you what to do if the `UserId` is a `Guid`.

Comment: i corrected that but can you sugguest me how to print gridview to excel ?? after page load on button

Comment: There are plenty of questions on stackoverflow regarding exporting a GridView to excel. I recommend using `EppPlus` to create a real excel file.